# Why do we take electric field inside resistor constant?

Tags: electricity, electric-current

Why do we take electric field inside resistor constant

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field in a resistor is the voltage gradient along the length of the resistor. Unless otherwise specified the resistance per unit length is generally considered constant, meaning for a given voltage across the resistor the electric field would be considered constant.

Hope this helps.